# how to make unity available on login-screen

Tags: unity, login-screen

I've installed unity over kubuntu 15.10 and I can see it on the login screen.

how could I do to make it available?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also installed the `unity-greeter` package.

You can install it via `sudo apt-get install unity-greeter` from the terminal. Or search for this packages with your preferred package managemetn tool.